# How to display div with position absolute outside of container scrolled?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a dropdown search. But I found a problem when using a container with a scroll.
[image]

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid gray 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  
  transform: none;
  position: relative;
  background: #337ab7 !important;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 60px;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As can see the list of dropdown was cut.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have `overflow: auto` on two elements, so the outer one scrolls first. You just have to be sure that the menu box doesn't render taller than the space available. You can also remove the outer scroll if it's not needed for other purposes.

```
.container {
    /* overflow: auto; */
}

.dropdown-content {
    max-height: 245px;
}
```

[**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kpg45m8c/)

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid gray 1px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    /* overflow: auto; */
    transform: none;
    position: relative;
    background: #337ab7 !important;
    transition: background-color .3s;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 60px;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    max-height: 245px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 2px solid red;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#base">Base</a>
        <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
        <a href="#support">Support</a>
        <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you'd rather not implement fixed heights, consider using a flexbox layout instead.

Comment: thanks, but how do you know the height? My example is simple, but the application I will use has several containers with different sizes.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do that, and the right one depends on your layout as a whole. It's hard for me to say with what little I know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if you wish to maintain the `scroll` of the `.container` and still show the `dropdown menu` entirely.

What I imagine is to put the menu out of the `.container` and everything inside a `wrapper`. The good thing is that `JavaScript` is being used, so it helps.

HTML would be like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  </div>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#base">Base</a>
      <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
      <a href="#support">Support</a>
      <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Than, you change the position of `.dropdown-content`:

```
.dropdown-content {
  left: 19px; // also top, right and bottom if you need
}
```

Hope it can be useful too.